# NXTComm driver error

Tags: java, nxt, lejos-nxj

We're trying to set up a NXT brick to use LEJOS so that we can program it using Java for a school project, but when we try to install the firmware we get a "Cannot load NXTComm driver" error. What else do need to do to get this to download properly?

This is the Progress Log:

```
Building firmware image.
VM file: C:\Program Files (x86)\leJOS NXJ\bin\lejos_nxt_rom.bin
Menu file: C:\Program Files (x86)\leJOS NXJ\bin\StartUpText.bin
Magic string found at offset 0x40
VM size: 55888 bytes.
Menu size: 47740 bytes.
Total image size 103804/104448 bytes.
Building filesystem image.
Locating device in firmware update mode.
```

Comment: Did you install the NXT Fantom driver found [here](http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads) on Lego's website?  Also, what Java are you using, and is it 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: We were able to re-download the NXT Fantom driver and got past this issue. However, when we tried flashing the firmware it stopped at 96%, and our computer can no longer recognize the brick. The brick makes a ticking sound about once every second (from it's speaker; it's not a hardware issue). Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Comment: You may wish to check out [this question](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6944/lego-mindstorms-nxt-bossa-driver-prevents-firmware-upgrade) which asks about the ticking and the bossa driver blocking it.  The ticking should be the brick waiting in firmware update mode.